# Boolean formula balancing in $\mathsf{AC^0}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, reference-request, lo.logic, boolean-formulas

I am looking for references about the complexity of *Boolean formula balancing* problem. In particular,

1. Was it known that Boolean formulas can be balanced in $\mathsf{AC^0}$?
2. Is there a simple proof of Boolean formula balancing being in $\mathsf{AC^0}$?

By "simple" I mean a proof simpler than the one I mention below, in particular I am looking for a proof which doesn't depend on Boolean formula evaluation being in $\mathsf{NC^1}$.

---

#### Background

Here all mentioned complexity classes are the uniform ones.

> **BFB** (Boolean formula balancing):
> Given a Boolean formula $\varphi$,
> Find an equivalent balanced Boolean formula.

I am interested in the complexity of this problem, in particular simple proofs showing the problem is in $\mathsf{AC^0}$ (or even $\mathsf{TC^0}$ or $\mathsf{NC^1}$). The common balancing arguments like those based on Spira's lemma apply repeated structural modifications to the formula tree which seem to only give $BFB \in \mathsf{NC^2}$.

I have a proof for $BFB \in \mathsf{AC^0}$, however the proof is not simple and depends on the proof of $BFE \in \mathsf{NC^1}$.

> **BFE** (Boolean formula evaluation)
> Given a Boolean formula $\varphi$ and a truth assignment $\tau$ for variables in $\varphi$,
> Does $\tau$ satisfy $\varphi$ ($\tau \vDash \varphi$)?

It is known from Sam Buss's celebrated result that *Boolean formula evaluation* ($BFE$) can be computed in $\mathsf{NC^1} = \mathsf{ALogTime}$ (see [[Buss87]](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/ResearchWeb/Boolean/) and  [[BCGR92]](http://euclid.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/ResearchWeb/Boolean2/)).

It follows (quite surprisingly, at least to me) that *Boolean formulas balancing* ($BFB$) is also in $\mathsf{NC^1}$:

The idea is that we can hardcode $\varphi$ in the input gates of $BFE$ to obtain a formula equivalent to $\varphi$ and this is a completely syntactic operation computable in $\mathsf{AC^0}$. Since $BFE$ has balanced formulas we obtain a equivalent balanced formula for $\varphi$. In other words, the algorithm is:

$$\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner \mapsto \ulcorner \lambda \vec{p}. Eval(\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner, \vec{p} )\urcorner$$

#### Motivation

A simpler argument for $BFB$ being in $\mathsf{AC^0}$ (or $\mathsf{TC^0}$ or even $\mathsf{NC^1}$) would give a new simpler proof of $BFE \in \mathsf{NC^1}$ since it is easy to see that the *balanced* version of BFE can be solved in $\mathsf{NC^1}$ and we can compose it with $BFB$ and the result will be in $\mathsf{NC^1}$.

---

#### Questions

1. Was it known that Boolean formulas can be balanced in $\mathsf{AC^0}$ ($BFB\in \mathsf{AC^1}$)?
2. Is there a simpler argument (e.g. not relying on $BFE\in \mathsf{NC^1}$) for $BFB\in\mathsf{AC^0}$?

Comment: What definition of "balance" do you use?

Comment: @Dana, we can use something like $Depth < 10\lg Size + 100 $ (i.e. $Depth = O(\lg Size)$ with specific constants). See also Bonnet and Buss's paper "[Size-Depth Tradeoff for Boolean Formulae](http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/fmlarestructure/paper.pdf)", 2002.

Comment: agreed the defn of "balancing" should be made clear. is this similar to the concept of balancing in binary trees? eg ["self balanced trees"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is very relevant but in [Log-Space Algorithms for Paths and Matchings in k-Trees](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00224-013-9469-9) (building on a long history of past work and specifically on [Arithmetizing classes around NC1 and L](http://www.imsc.res.in/~meena/papers/tocs-arithnc.pdf) by Limaye-Mahajan-Rao) we show how to find recursive balanced separators for a tree in Logspace. This bound may very well be improvable to $\mathsf{NC}^1$ if the input tree is directly given in the string representation.

The basic idea is to represent the tree as a parenthesis expression and find balanced separators for these. Notice that we find leaf separators i.e. subtrees which are balanced w.r.t. number of leaves.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this question now, many years later. In the interim the following paper has appeared:

https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3278158

https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08705

There the authors do precisely what Kaveh asks for in his question 2: they give a (uniform) TC0 algorithm for balancing, hence obtaining an alternative proof of the main result in Buss '87, as was the original motivation of this question.